# Importing Colab modules into Colab

Tags: python-3.x, module, google-colaboratory

I am new to using Colab, I want to create modules that are imported into other notebooks. I have tried a number of methods and the best I end up with is this error message:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import converters

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'converters'

Can you import a *.ipynb as a module into Colab?

I have mounted the gdrive and set the root dir - see code below.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/', force_remount=True)
root_dir = "content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/projects/utilities/"
base_dir = root_dir + "projects/"
```

I have tried other methods as well, I have also tried sharing the notebook. help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
# (1) Mount your google drive in google colab
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# (2) Insert the directory using sys
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,’/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/projects/utilities/’)

# Import your module or file
import my_module
```

OR

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/projects/utilities/')
!cp -r "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/projects/utilities/my_module.ipynb" '/content/'
```